# Condensation resistant humidity sensor

Tags: sensor, humidity

I am working on the controller for a product that incorporates a humidity controlled chamber, such chamber is (generally) kept at rh80-95% but, even in normal usage, it is possible and acceptable that the humidity reaches 100% and condensing.

Honeywell HIH sensors, http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=147072 , look great for the task, however they make a dinstinction between sensor that are suited for up to rh100% and those who are suited for rh100% and condensing.

Seems that the only difference between the two versions is the presence of a little "net" in front of the sensor orifice. 
Can I just use (for economical reasons outside the purpose of this question) the "non-condensing" version and protect it with a fine mesh in front of the orifice or the under-the-hood difference between the two is bigger that the physical protection of the sensor??

Thankyou

Comment: Are they really so much cheaper that it pays out to make the filter yourself?

Comment: Definitely yes.

Comment: It might be possible that the sensor suited for no condensation will get problems with stability and reliability when used with condensation. You will not be sure that your protection with a fine mesh will prevent those problems for the next years. What if the product frequently fails after some time because the wrong sensor was used?

Comment: Unless we`ll know factually that the only difference is the mesh we will go for the more expensive protected sensor